# Stored procedure that filter, sort, support paging and do some extra functionality on the resultset

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sorting, stored-procedures

I'm looking for an expert advice to fine tune the sample stored procedure ( MS SQL 2008R2)  for performance gain as well as to follow best practices.

To explain my requirements I have created a sample procedure below.

The procedure needs to do the following

1. Needs to filter based on the parameters.
2. Sort the data based on the `@SortExpression` eg. `Code Desc` or `ImpDate ASC`
3. Return total record count of entire record set.
4. Return totals of a field in the entire record set .
5. finally return only a subset of record set based on the `startRowIndex` and page size

   ```
   CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[_getlist](@CompanyID      VARCHAR(10),
                             @IsPaid         VARCHAR(3),
                             @Code           VARCHAR(10) = NULL,
                             @ImpDate        DATETIME = NULL,
                             @BatchNo        INT,
                             @StartRowIndex  INT,
                             @PageSize       INT,
                             @SortExpression VARCHAR(50),
                             @TotalAmount    NUMERIC(15, 2) output,
                             @RecordCount    INT output)
   AS
   BEGIN
      DECLARE @SortDirection VARCHAR(10)

      SET @SortDirection = 'ASC'

      IF RIGHT(@SortExpression, 5) = ' DESC'
         SET @SortDirection = 'DESC'

      DECLARE @SortColumn VARCHAR(50)

      SELECT @SortColumn = Replace(@SortExpression, ' ASC', '')

      SELECT @SortColumn = Replace(@SortColumn, ' DESC', '')

      DECLARE @StartIndex INT,
              @EndIndex   INT

      SET @StartIndex = @StartRowIndex
      SET @EndIndex = @StartRowIndex + @PageSize -- (@CurrentPage + 1 )

      SELECT data.,
        Row_number()
          OVER (
            ORDER BY CASE WHEN @SortDirection = 'DESC' THEN CASE WHEN
          @SortColumn
          =
          'code' THEN data.client_code END END DESC, CASE WHEN
          @SortDirection
          =
          'ASC'
          THEN CASE WHEN @SortColumn = 'code' THEN data.client_code END END
          ASC )
        AS
        RowNumber
    INTO   #temptable
    FROM   (SELECT *
            FROM   clients
            WHERE  is_local = 'Yes'
                AND is_paid = 'No'
                AND status = 'Valid'
                AND ( company_id = @CompanyID )
                AND ( ispaid = @IsPaid
                       OR @IsPaid IS NULL )
                AND ( code = @Code
                       OR @Code IS NULL )
                AND ( @ImpDate IS NULL
                       OR import_date = @ImpDate )
                AND ( @BatchNo = 0
                       OR batch_no = @BatchNo )) AS data

     SELECT @RecordCount = Count(*)
     FROM   #temptable

     SELECT @TotalAmount = Sum(total_tax)
     FROM   #temptable

     SELECT *
     FROM   #temptable
     WHERE  rownumber >= @StartIndex
            AND ( rownumber <= @EndIndex OR @PageSize = -1 )

     DROP TABLE #temptable
   END
   ```

The sample is just to explain the requirements. I really appreciate any help that could help me out.

Update: As mention before this is just a cooked up sample to communicate the the requirements.

Here is the client table schema

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Client](   
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,   
    [CODE] [char](10) NULL,   
    [COMPANY_ID] [char](6) NOT NULL,   
    [CLIENT_ID] [char](6) NOT NULL,   
    [IMP_DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,   
    [BATCH_NO] [int] NOT NULL,   
    [YTD_Total] [numeric](15, 2) NOT NULL,   
    [STATUS] [char](5) NOT NULL,   
    [MODIFY_DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,   
    [MODIFY_BY] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,   
    [NOTES] [varchar](100) NULL,   
    [ISPAID] [char](3) NOT NULL,   
    [msrepl_tran_version] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL   
)
```

Thanks,

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Comment: @marc_s Taht's definitely SQL Server and T-SQL.  I can't tell what version though.

Comment: We will also need the [clients] table definition, including keys and indexes.

Comment: RBarryYoung, Updated with table definition. Please note that this just a cooked up sample explaining the requirements

Answer (score 1):

For paging with T-SQL, I would recommend looking at SQL Server Common Table Expressions. See example #2 from this link:

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1699/sql-server-stored-procedures-to-page-large-tables-or-queries/

The performance metrics are listed at the bottom--you can see that it is incredibly faster and more efficient than using temp tables (example #1).

Comment: We use a derivation of the CTE method (example 2 at that link).  Our prod systems typically have around 200k records or so while we show around 40 at a time.  From a performance perspective it's pretty close to perfect.

Comment: Jeff thanks for taking time to answer. CTE method will definitely be faster but in CTE is available to use only once. In my case i need to do more than one operation from the result set. That is after getting the result set I need to get the total count from entire result set, then perform sum operation on the result set  and then return the page result set.  If i use CTE then i have to repeat the query multiple times which is redundant code and hard to maintain. Please advise if my think is correct. Thanks